# Why is there no logs using "docker run image command" to start container?

Tags: git, docker, gitlab

I use the `docker run genezys/gitlab:7.5.2` command to create and start a container:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker run genezys/gitlab:7.5.2
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 34: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 37: /proc/sys/fs/file-max: Read-only file system
[2015-05-05T05:43:02+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
......
```

I can see there are logs outputted in terminal.

But when I use `docker run genezys/gitlab:7.5.2 /bin/true` command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker run genezys/gitlab:7.5.2 /bin/true
[root@localhost ~]#
```

There is no logs outputted.

Why is there no logs using `docker run image command` to start container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be because the  `/bin/true` CMD (from `docker run genezys/gitlab:7.5.2 /bin/true`) overwrites the original CMD defined [in the Dockerfile](https://github.com/genezys/docker-gitlab/blob/2129bf018998e1d4bb0295c70d921cbe3419c062/Dockerfile#L43):

```
# Default is to run runit & reconfigure
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/gitlab.sh"]
```

Since GitLab is never run (with `/bin/true`), it never outputs any log.

---

The [`docker run`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run) has a `COMMAND` parameter:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

The [docker run "Overriding Dockerfile image defaults"](http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#overriding-dockerfile-image-defaults) mentions:

> Four of the Dockerfile commands cannot be overridden at runtime: `FROM`, `MAINTAINER`, `RUN`, and `ADD`.
>   **Everything else has a corresponding override in `docker run`**.

That includes `CMD`:

> Recall the optional `COMMAND` in the Docker commandline:

```
$ sudo docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

> This command is optional because the person who created the IMAGE may have already provided a default `COMMAND` using the Dockerfile `CMD` instruction.
>   **As the operator (the person running a container from the image), you can override that `CMD` instruction just by specifying a new `COMMAND`.**
>
> If the image also specifies an `ENTRYPOINT` then the `CMD` or `COMMAND` get appended as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: Firstly, thanks very much for your kind and quick response for every `docker` question! The CMD from command line will overwrite the CMD in `Dockerfile`, is it applicable for all `docker` images? Is there any reference from official site?

Comment: @NanXiao I have edited the answer to include the relevant extract from the official documentation: It confirms that the `COMMAND` `/bin/true` is overriding the image `CMD` `/usr/local/bin/gitlab.sh`.